# Convert 5 digit zip code to 3 digit zip code in R

Tags: r

I have a large data set and all the zip codes are in 5 digit numeric form.  I need to take these and make them in to 3 digit zip codes (so that it keeps the first 3 digits of the zip code, including any 0s).  So

```
State Zip
A     12345
```

becomes

```
State Zip
A     123
```

How is this done?

Comment: I suggest using `substr` function, specifically `substr(df$Zip,1,3)` where `df` refers to the name of your data.frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to string, then trim it:

```
> zip=12345
> strtrim(as.character(zip), 3)
[1] "123"
```

Then you can convert back to a number.